# How get user name from the userId to display in a post?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi everyone I am trying to add the user's name in the post that is being created by that user but I'm running into trouble.

This is the part of the post where the user's name should be displayed

```
<Link style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}>
   <h4
     onClick={() => this.handleShowUserProfile(event.userId)}
     className="host-name"
   >
    {getUser(event.userId).name}
   </h4>
</Link>
```

This is where the user is being grabbed from the database

```
import http from "./httpService";

const apiEndPoint = "http://localhost:3100/api/users";

export function getUsers() {
  return http.get(apiEndPoint);
}
export function getUser(userId) {
  return http.get(apiEndPoint + "/" + userId);
}
```

in the backend this is how the user schema looks like

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 50
  },
  bio: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 200,
    maxlength: 400
  },
  interests: {
    type: Array
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 255,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 1024
  },
  isAdmin: Boolean
});

userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
  const token = jwt.sign(
    { _id: this._id, isAdmin: this.isAdmin },
    config.get("jwtPrivateKey")
  );
  return token;
};

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
function validateUser(user) {
  const schema = {
    name: Joi.string()
      .min(5)
      .max(50)
      .required(),
    bio: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .min(200)
      .max(400),
    interests: Joi.array().required(),
    email: Joi.string()
      .min(5)
      .max(255)
      .required()
      .email(),
    password: Joi.string()
      .min(5)
      .max(255)
      .required()
  };

  return Joi.validate(user, schema);
}

module.exports.User = User;
module.exports.validate = validateUser;
```

this is the event schema...

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { categorySchema } = require("./category");
const { userSchema } = require("./user");

const Event = mongoose.model(
  "Events",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    image: {
      type: String
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 50,
      trim: true
    },
    user: {
      type: userSchema,
      required: true
    },
    details: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      minlength: 200,
      maxlength: 300,
      trim: true
    },
    category: {
      type: categorySchema,
      required: true
    },
    numOfAttendies: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 10000
    }
  })
);
```

this is the handleShowUserProfile

```
handleShowUserProfile = id => {
   this.setState({
     showUserProfile: true,
     shownUserID: id,
     user: getUser(id)
   });
 };

 handleHideUserProfile = () => {
   this.setState({
     showUserProfile: false
   });
 };
```

Comment: can you post code for handleShowUserProfile?

Comment: handleShowUserProfile = id => {
    this.setState({
      showUserProfile: true,
      shownUserID: id,
      user: getUser(id)
    });
  };

  handleHideUserProfile = () => {
    this.setState({
      showUserProfile: false
    });
  };

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, `getUser()` likely returns a promise, not a value. You'll need to look into reading the name from props(state) and updating state instead of trying to do it all right there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your handleShowUserProfile  method like the following?

```
handleShowUserProfile = async (id) => {

    const user = await getUser(id);
    this.setState({
      showUserProfile: true,
      shownUserID: id,
      user: user
    });
  };
```

I assume your api returns data for http://localhost:3100/api/users/:userId endpoint.

After you check your api and sure that it returns data, you need to check if you send a valid userId in this line.

```
 onClick={() => this.handleShowUserProfile(event.userId)}
```

Lastly you should also change the following line since the user data is in the state.

```
 {getUser(event.userId).name}  => {this.state.user && this.state.user.name }
```

Comment: i did but the name still doesn't display

Comment: can you console.log(user)  the user after line const user = await getUser(id);

Comment: it return.... createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404 GET http://localhost:3100/api/users/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Sami you are sending undefined as userId, Can you post all the code in your component?

Comment: Here  event.userId is undefined, we need to fix this first.
 onClick={() => this.handleShowUserProfile(event.userId)}

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out that get request. See if the results it returns match up with what you're trying to get from it.

```
export function getUser(userId) {
  const results = http.get(apiEndPoint + "/" + userId);
  console.log("results of getUser ::: ", results)
  return results
}
```

Comment: Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseValue]]: Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: Nice! looks like you're returning a promise. You will need to use a `.then()` or an `await` (`async`). It also looks like your request is rejected. Once you have access to the request (not the promise), check the apiEndPoint, the request method and the userId to be sure everything is correct. I recommend logging out `apiEndPoint + "/" + userId` to make sure it's absolutely correct!

Answer (score 0):

The *getUser* function is an asynchronous function so it will return a promise in most cases you need to use state and the lifecycle methods to fetch and set the username.